# uniform bounds on Weyl Equidistribution theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

If $\theta \notin \mathbb{Q}$ the sequence $\{ n \theta\}$ is equidstributed mod 1. If we let $f \in L^2 ([0,1])$ and $T: x \mapsto x + \theta $ this could be phrased a special case of the [ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem):

$$ \frac{1}{N} \big[ \, f(x) + f(T_\theta \,x) + \dots + f(T_\theta^{N-1}\,x) \,\big] = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx $$

It is possible to ask for quantitative equidstribution theorems, do we have estimates of the error

$$ \bigg| \frac{1}{N} \big[ \, f(x) + f(T_\theta \,x) + \dots + f(T_\theta^{N-1}\,x) \,\big]  - \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \bigg|  <_{N, f}  \hspace{0.125in} ???$$
that are uniform in $\theta \in [0,1]$ almost everywhere or set of measure $1 - \epsilon$ ?

---

Put another way, are there variants of the ergodic theorem that work for families of maps $T_\theta: X \to X$ rather than just a single map?

Comment: It wouldn't probably be uniform for all $\theta\in[0,1]$: for small $\theta$ you need large $N$ for the ergodicity to kick in.

Comment: As long as there are Liouvillian numbers, you will not have a uniform bound, as can be seen by directly computing the sum over characters. You can deduce a uniform bound over diophantine numbers, moreover, you need to bound the regularity of the function at hand (at-least Lipschitz type, probably you will want some control over the Fourier expansion, i.e. Sobolev spaces). I suggest looking at Einsiedler's notes about quantitative equidistribution for a nice discussion of those matters.

Comment: @Asaf The error should depend on $f$ and perhaps on $N$ as well.  Perhaps it is $O(1)$ if you exclude enough numbers or $O(N)$.

Comment: The error definitely depends on $f$ but you cannot make it uniform over $\theta$ as you will have Liouvillian $\theta$. It is very easy to show that (Lebesgue) a.e. number is Diophantine and as a result get such uniform rate for Diophantine rotations (depending on the function regularity). This is done in Green-Tao article for example (for general Nilflows), but I'm suggesting working the Kronecker system case first, before going to the Green-Tao article.

Comment: Moreover, for general dynamical systems, if the system is not uniquely ergodic, it does not always hold that the rate is uniform even on the different trajectories (i.e. your starting point $x$). In the uniquely ergodic case, it follows by a famous theorem of Furstenberg that you have a uniform rate over all your starting points $x$.

P.S. As $f$ is in $L^{2}$, this sum does not have any reasonable meaning (pointwise), you should work with $C_{c}$ functions or so.

Comment: @Asaf all I had in mind were rotations -- and don't take my choice of $f \in L^2$ to heart as it is merely to make the statement correct -- at least I get a Fourier series.  I sort of assumed the only invariant measure would be $\mu = dx$.

Comment: If you are using the pointwise ergodic theorem why pick your function from $L^2([0,1])$ rather then the larger space $L^1([0,1])$, where pointwise convergence (a.e.) occurs?

Comment: the difference between these two spaces is not an issue I have ever appreciated except on a formal level

Comment: @kconrad there is some overlap I think... the mean ergodic theorem and pointwise ergodic theorem produce related statements. $L^2$ emphasizes Hilbert space geometry and $L^1$ emphasizes measure and Poincare recurrence

Comment: There are some nice theorems bounding the difference between the integral and the sum in terms of the variation of the function and the discrepancy of the sequence (e.g., Koksma, and Erdos-Turan), and also there are theorems on the discrepancy of your sequence. I'd recommend consulting the Kuipers and Niederreiter book on uniform distribution of sequences.

Comment: @GerryMyerson then I have to estimate the variation of $f$ and the discrepancy of the orbit $T^n(x)$ but yes that's exactly the book I am looking at.

Comment: For any dynamical system, there is no rate in the ergodic theorem for $L^2$ functions (see the paper of Krengel has a paper on this).  As mentioned before by Asaf and GerryMyerson, if you restrict yourself to a specific nice function (e.g. Lipshitz, bounded variation, Fourier coefficients type conditions) it is possible to get rates in the ergodic theorem for a class of angles $theta$. In both cases this will involve diophantine conditions. One approach is to get rates in the mean ergodic theorem using Fourier analysis and then use the Borel Cantelli lemmas.